# Why does the AndroidView with Compose always have a white background color?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

I am working on an Android project in which I have to use an Android View in Compose. However, when I used it, the Android View always has a white background. Can somebody help me?
My code:

```kotlin
AndroidView(factory = {
    val textView = TextView(it).apply {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
    }
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent)
    textView.text = "why is there not transparent?"
    return@AndroidView textView
}, modifier = modifier
    .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
    .height(128.dp)
    .background(Color.Transparent)
)
```

I got the following screen:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake, I have a item `android:background` in themes.xml